# Run time error 1004: Application or User Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba

I have just started using VBA and every error and its mother keeps popping up. This is the most recent one and since it is for an external object, I imagine the documentation I would have to go to to find out is extensive. If you would be so kind as to point out what is causing this (and any other errors you might see) from preventing the code from running.

I have programmed in java before, so I have a reasonable conceptual grasp and know what I want to do. I'm not interested in obscure ways to make my method run more efficiently. I just want it to work. I'm fairly certain my main issue is with errors preventing it from executing, so, again, please point them out.

```
Sub findRawMaterial()
Dim currentSheet As String
currentSheet = "Sheet1"
Dim currentProduct As String
Dim blankTest As Boolean
blankTest = False
Dim currentRow As Integer
currentRow = 2
Dim currentProductNumber As String
Dim currentMaterialNumber As String
Dim rowAmount As Integer
rowAmount = 10

Do While blankTest = False
currentProductNumber = CStr(Worksheets("Sheet2").WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(currentRow - 2, 2).Value))
currentMaterialNumber =  CStr(Worksheets("Sheet2").WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(currentRow - 2, 5).Value))

Dim i As Integer
For i = 4 To rowAmount

    If currentProductNumber = WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(i, 1)) Then

        If IsEmpty(Range("C" + CStr(i)).Value) Then

        Set Cells(i, 3).Value = currentMaterialNumber

        Else
        Rows(currentRow + 1).Insert.EntireRow
        Set Range("C" + CStr(i + 1)).Value = currentMaterialNumber
        End If
    End If
Next i
If IsEmpty(Range("W" + CStr(currentRow))) Then
blankTest = True
End If
currentRow = currentRow + 1
Loop
Dim index As Integer

End Sub
```

Comment: WADR, I would have preferred knowing what line of code generated the error that the short history lesson you offered.

Comment: The only difference between the worksheet [TRIM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) and the VBA [Trim function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9wz3dez%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is the removal of double spaces within the string. Is this a concern?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the reason you get that error.
You are pointing cells where location (0,2).
For your information, the location for Column A Row 1 is (1,1).
Moreover, the worksheetFunction does not support the "Trim" like that.
I done the correction for you. Hope it help

```
currentProductNumber = CStr(Worksheets("Sheet2").WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(currentRow - 2, 2).Value))
currentMaterialNumber = CStr(Worksheets("Sheet2").WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cells(currentRow - 2, 5).Value))
```

The correct one should be:

```
currentProductNumber = CStr(Trim(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(currentRow - 1, 2).Value))
currentMaterialNumber = CStr(Trim(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(currentRow - 1, 5).Value))
```

Comment: ++ Good catch on starting at Row 0. I completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not *Set* values; that is only for objects like ranges or worksheets, etc.
2. Your code relies on the implicit reference to the active sheet which I would assume is **Sheet2**. Better to use a [With...End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) and explicitly define the worksheet parent of all `.Cells` and `.Range` references within the With/End With by prefixing with a period (i.e. `.` or *full-stop*).
3. Unless you use these as a visual coding reference, most of the `CStr` conversions were unnecessary. Besides, using `Trim` is going to output a string value.
4. Just about any Integer type variable should be a Long.

Here is a quick rewrite of the code you supplied.

```
Sub findRawMaterial()
    Dim currentSheet As String, currentProduct As String
    Dim blankTest As Boolean
    Dim currentProductNumber As String, currentMaterialNumber As String
    Dim i As Long, rowAmount As Long, currentRow As Long

    Dim wf: Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    currentSheet = "Sheet1"
    currentRow = 2
    rowAmount = 10
    blankTest = False

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Do While blankTest = False
            currentProductNumber = wf.Trim(.Cells(currentRow - 1, 2).Value2)
            currentMaterialNumber = wf.Trim(.Cells(currentRow - 1, 5).Value2)

            For i = 4 To rowAmount
                If currentProductNumber = wf.Trim(.Cells(i, 1)) Then

                    If IsEmpty(.Range("C" + i).Value) Then
                        .Cells(i, 3).Value = currentMaterialNumber
                    Else
                        .Rows(currentRow + 1).Insert.EntireRow
                        .Range("C" + i + 1).Value = currentMaterialNumber
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            If IsEmpty(Range("W" + currentRow)) Then
                blankTest = True
            End If
            currentRow = currentRow + 1   'should this be incremented before checking column W?
        Loop
    End With

    Dim index As Integer  ' what is this doing here

End Sub
```

That's about all I can do without seeing sample data.